# Using cards within my list as a checklist

Tags: trello-cards

I would like each card in my list to be a "to do" item that I can check off as I complete them.  How can I identify each card as "completed" once I've completed it?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to have a Todo list and a Done list, one an item has been completed, you just drag the card from the Todo list into the Done list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this several ways, depending how you want to organize your lists and flow. There is no "this card is completed" function per se, it should be defined in a different way. The first (seperate list) is my favorite, but the second works as well for some projects. I wouldn't personally use my third option, but it is a valid method I guess.

- 'standard' left-to-right flow: Make a *ToDo* and *Done* list or even a *ToDo*, *Doing* and *Done* list. Move the cards from left to right. Drag them with your mouse or use <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>
- Archive all done tasks, via the card's menu or using <kbd>c</kbd>
- You can use labels. No label for 'random' cards, and a label for done. Maybe also a label for 'doing'. Use the menu on a card, or <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> etc keyboard shortcuts

There are probably more things you can think of, like assigning todo's to yourself and removing the assignement if it is done, or the other way around, assigning yourself if you have done it, although that would mess up your 'cards' view a bit with completed tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the way you are organizing your information a bit, then you could make use of the Checklist feature that each card has. This would allow you to easily check-off items as they are completed.